# How to Select All with a One to Many Relationship Using Linq

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, one-to-many

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Thing (
    Id int,
    Name nvarchar(max)
);

CREATE TABLE SubThing (
        Id int,
        Name nvarchar(max),
        ThingId int (foreign key)
    );
```

I want to select all Things with a listing of SubThings and set them to a ThingViewModel.

The Thing ViewModel is simple:

```
public class ThingViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<SubThingViewModel> SubThings { get; set; }
}
```

The SubThingViewModel is:

```
public class SubThingViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

I already select the Thing records like this:

```
List<ThingViewModel> things = null;
things = _context.Things.OrderBy(b => b.Name)
    .Select(b => new ThingViewModel
    {
         Id = b.Id,
         Name = b.Name
    }).ToList();
```

How would I add the SubThings to the query and ViewModel?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do another projection using `SubThings` [navigation property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713564(v=vs.113).aspx):

```
things = _context.Things.OrderBy(b => b.Name)
.Select(b => new ThingViewModel
{
     Id = b.Id,
     Name = b.Name,
     SubThings =b.SubThings.Select(st=>new SubThingViewModel{Id =st.Id,...}).ToList()
}).ToList();
```

Comment: I'll add the SubThings ViewModel to the post to make it more clear. Would I also need a .ToList() at the end of this line:

SubThings =b.SunThings.Select(st=>new SubThingViewModel{Id =st.Id,...})

Comment: Right, `SubThings` in the root ViewModel class is a List, thanks ;)

Comment: No worries. I just want to make this a useful post 10 years from now.