# How can I use Linq to include a List<myDto> in selectTableDto?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am currently using Linq to join two tables together, mainTable and selectTable, they are joined on mainTable.ID = selectTable.mtID. I am trying to include a third table, myTable, that is joined on selectTable.ID = myTable.selID. There will be many records in myTable for one ID from selectTable so I'm trying to get `List<myTable>`. This is what I have so far that works:

```
public async Task<List<mainTableDto>> listAll()
{
     var db = _repository.DbContext;
     var result = await ( from mt in db.mainTable
                    join sel in db.selectTable
                    on mt.ID equals sel.mtID
                    select new mainTableDto
                    {
                         ID = mt.ID,
                         createDate = mt.createDate,
                         selectTable = new selectTableDto
                         {
                               ID = sel.ID
                               name = sel.name
                          }
                    }                              
}).ToListAsync;

return result;
```

I've tested getting data from selectTableDto with `List< myTableDto>` and it works.
I'm a little stuck on how to include a `List<myTableDto>` into this nested call. I've tried:

```
join sel in db.selectTableInclude(x=>x.myTableDto)
```

But when I do this I don't get the info from myTableDto and just get null instead (I've put data in the DB so there should be something)
I've also tried:

```
                    join sel in db.selectTable
                    on mt.ID equals sel.mtID
                    join my in db.myTable
                    on sel.ID equals my.selID

                         selectTable = new selectTableDto
                         {
                               ID = sel.ID
                               name = sel.name
                               myTableDto = new List<myTableDto>
                               {
                                    ID = my.ID
                               }
                          }
```

But when I do this it says "ID is not a member of myTableDTO".

Any advice on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: *I'm a little stuck on how to include a List into this call* - I'm a little stuck on how to understand this:) What does your list contain? How does it relate to the other entities?

Comment: @CaiusJard I edited it so hopefully it is a little more clear on how selectTable and myTable are related and for some reason List< mytable> wasn't showing up properly.

Comment: Ah, now I get it - markdown was interpreting your `<mytable>` as html tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want a groupjoin (method syntax) or `into` (query syntax)

This is query syntax:

```
from mt in db.mainTable
join sel in db.selectTable
  on mt.ID equals sel.mtID
  into mainTableSels
select new mainTableDto
{
     ID = mt.ID,
     createDate = mt.createDate,
     selectTable = from mts in mainTableSels select new selectTableDto
     {
         ID = mts.ID
         name = mts.name
     }
}
```

Though I do personally prefer a hybrid query/method syntax:

```
from mt in db.mainTable
join sel in db.selectTable
  on mt.ID equals sel.mtID
  into mainTableSels
select new mainTableDto
{
     ID = mt.ID,
     createDate = mt.createDate,
     selectTable =  mainTableSels.Select(mts => new selectTableDto
     {
         ID = mts.ID
         name = mts.name
     })
}
```

I'm not clear on what type your `mainTableDto.selectTable` property is; if it's an array or list you'll need a ToArray/ToList. If it's IEnumerable then it should work without

Comment: I can get mainTable and selectTable to join and I get the appropriate data. The issue I'm having is, after those 2 tables are joined, joining myTable into selectTable. If I didn't need to have List<myTable> it would work but I can't seem to figure out how to get this List<myTable> in there

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused as to what a myTable is. I assumed that you're struggling because you were just straight joining mainTable to selectTable and getting mainTable repeated over and over with mainTable and selectTable joined so there is a 1:1 mapping, when what you wanted was all the mainTable and each having a list of selectTable that relate. What's a `myTable`?

Comment: Damn I'm dumb, I was able to figure it out. I for some reason I wasn't looking at how to do a one-to-many relationship in Linq. I got the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43683677/how-to-select-all-with-a-one-to-many-relationship-using-linq Thanks for the help though